# Enable kubernetes nginx ingress compression in terraform configuration

Tags: nginx, terraform, nginx-ingress

using helm bitnami chart nginx-ingress-controller and also this terraform code to create the controller, how to enable the gzip request compression? it seems to be configmap option use-gzip="true" but how to enable it here?

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "nginx" {

  metadata {
    name      = "${data.terraform_remote_state.main.outputs.app_name}-ingress"
    namespace = "default"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"                             = "nginx"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect"                = "true"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size"           = "128k"

    }
  }
  spec {
    tls {
      secret_name = data.terraform_remote_state.main.outputs.tls_secret_name
    }
    #ui
    rule {
      host = "myhost.com"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/"
          backend {
            service_name = "mybackend"
            service_port = "80"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you would probably enable it on the Deployment/Pod level.

Comment: @Gabriel Robledo Ahumada I have accidentally declined the edit request to remove the `kubernetes` tag, but now I saw that `kubernetes` tag is not intended for configuration problems. However I can not undo my review. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186737/372964 Maybe the original author can edit the question and remove the tag?

Comment: user643011 edit seems not possible - when i click on it, it shows message "Approve, reject, or improve this suggested edit.". Not sure, may is too late now.